# Trigonometric Integral Help

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

How would I go about integrating the following?

$$\int sin(x)sec^5(x)dx$$

Comment: $\sin x \sec^5 x = \frac {\sin x}{\cos^5 x}, u = \cos x, du = -\sin x dx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Observe
\begin{align}
\int \tan x \sec^4 x\ dx = \int (\tan x \sec x) \sec^3 x\ dx
\end{align}
then $u$-sub where $u = \sec x$.

Comment: ahh, so change sec into 1/cos then make it into tan?

Comment: Yes.  That's the trick.